# Golang exec.Command StdoutPipe & StderrPipe empty for X seconds on invalid ip

Tags: linux, go, operating-system

I am building a utility where any linux command can be executed via UI. I receive the command on backend, then i run the command on the host machine and capture the output

```
    func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("ping", "-c", "10", "2.2.2.2")

    stdOut, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stdErr, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        if err1 := CaptureOutput(stdOut); err1 != nil {
            fmt.Sprintf("%v", err1)
        }

        if err2 := CaptureOutput(stdErr); err2 != nil {
            fmt.Sprintf("%v", err2)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    cmd.Start()

    execErr := cmd.Wait()
    if execErr != nil {
        if exitError, ok := execErr.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
            fmt.Println(exitError.ExitCode())
        }
    }

}

func CaptureOutput(r io.Reader) error {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        fmt.Println("Waiting on Reader")
        n, err := r.Read(buf[:])
        zap.L().Sugar().Infof("Read  %d bytes", n)
        if n > 0 {
            d := buf[:n]
            fmt.Println("Out------" + string(d))
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                err = nil
            }
            return err
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is if the ip is invalid the program waits at `n, err := r.Read(buf[:])` its not able to capture the first line `PING 2.2.2.2 (2.2.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.`
But when its a valid ip it does print correctly.

I tried reducing the buffer size, but data is read into byte buff only after the  `10` tries are done

Comment: Try reading line by line using bufio.

Comment: Unrelated, why would you ever write `buf[:]`? That slice expression does nothing, where did it come from?